# Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in Test.ovpn:1: ÿþc (2.4.9)

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in Test.ovpn:1: ÿþc (2.4.9)
Use --help for more information.
```

I am quite confused with this error with my `ovpn` file... I have looked into this issue and the issue should be listed after the `Test.ovpn:1`, however, my `ovpn` file has no traces of the word `ÿþc`. What could this mean? What can I do to fix it?

Test.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp4-client
remote <IP> 
port <Port>
tls-client
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 1
remote-cert-tls server
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\Test.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\Test.key"

cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
mute 20
```

---

<sub>The `<IP>` and `<Port>` are the actual ports in the ovpn file...</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like OVPN is parsing your .opvn file differently compared to your editor. This is usually to either an encoding problem, or your text editor is adding additional hidden characters to the file that shouldn't be there (a common problem is Wordpad is used to edit a file)